# Given a basis $U$, what conditions are needed for an orthogonal basis for it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition

Given a basis $U$, what conditions are needed for an orthogonal basis for it?

For example, in the following vector space $U$, if $U =sp\{(1,1,1),(1,3,7)\}$ then what conditions are needed for an orthogonal basis for it?

Is it enough to have a basis of dimension $2$ that's orthogonal? or are there more conditions?

EDIT: If for example I find an orthogonal span of dimension 2, say $V=sp\{(1,1,1), v_2\} $ such that $v_2$ is orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$, is any vector that's orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$ fine for it to be an orthogonal span for $U$?

PS: I know there's GS algorithm, but I'm asking if other bases that we get in other ways are also fine.

Comment: $U$ is no basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is enough to have $n$ pairwise orthogonal vectors in a $n$ dimensional space to get an orthogonal basis. (linear independence follows from orthogonality).

Comment: Well let's say a basis for $U$ and not for $\mathbb R^3$ then. @sigmabe

Comment: $U$ is a set of two vectors, it is no vectorspace and so it hasn't a vectorspace basis.

Comment: So one can't say that $U$ is a basis at all? @sigmabe

Comment: An orthogonal basis is just a basis that is pairwise orthogonal. Maybe you should spell out both definitions to yourself.

Comment: @sigmabe, forgot the span there.

Comment: Given any subspace of ${\bf R}^n$, there is an orthogonal basis for that subspace. Given any basis for a subspace of ${\bf R}^n$, you can use GS to construct an orthogonal basis for that subspace. Every basis is fine, but the orthogonal ones are finer. Your question is exceedingly unclear. What do you really mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson added some more clarification.

Comment: OK, now that you have edited it, the answer is, of course not. If you just take any old vector orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$, there's no reason to think you will get $(1,3,7)$ in the span, so no reason to think you will get $U$. Think geometrically! You have a plane, you have one vector in that plane, you take a second vector orthogonal to the first one, if that second vector is not in the plane, then the two vectors can't possibly be a basis for the plane!

Comment: @GerryMyerson yeah I see it now... thanks.

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write up what you now understand, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U=sp\{u_1,u_2\}$ is a plane, then any span where $sp\{u_1,v_1\}: v_1\perp u_1$ doesn't necessarily span the same plane as U. So we we can't just take any vector that's orthogonal to $u_1$ as $v_1$.

Thanks Gerry Myerson.